# error while sending mail to arrays of internetAddress using java

Tags: java, email

I wanna code a java application tto send mail to multiple address stocked in a file txt (each line equal to an email address).
So first I read the file line  by line and I got an arraylist of emails(I tested individualy and it's work nice ).

Please help me to overcome error:
This is a part of the code:

```
     try {
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(filepath ));
         ArrayList<String> emails =new ArrayList<>();
           String s;

          while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
                emails.add(s);
                }
                in.close();

       int size = emails.size();
       InternetAddress[] addresses = new InternetAddress[size];
          for (int i =0;i < size;i++) {
                    try {
      addresses[i] = new InternetAddress((emails.get(i).trim())); // line cause the problem
  
     // addresses[i] = new InternetAddress(props.getProperty(emails.get(i).trim()));
                     } catch (AddressException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addresses);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

````
I got this error: 

 javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Illegal address in string ``''
 at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.<init>(InternetAddress.java:122)
 at SendMails.main

 at line ```addresses[i] = new InternetAddress((emails.get(i).trim())); ```// line cause the 
 problem

  when I try ```addresses[i] = new 
 InternetAddress(props.getProperty(emails.get(i).trim()));```
I got this error: 
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.parse(InternetAddress.java:793)
at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.parse(InternetAddress.java:752)
at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.<init>(InternetAddress.java:119)
at SendMails.main
````

Comment: It seems like at least one of those strings isn't an actual email address and thus can't be used. You'd need to check that (e.g. by catching the exception and ignoring and/or reporting that address) and build an array of only valid `InternetAddress` elements. Since you'd not know how many that would be you should try to build a list first and convert that to an array only when you need to set the recipients.

Comment: @ManeeshaIndrachapa how should that help?  `(emails.get(i)).trim()` and `emails.get(i).trim()` are functionally equivalent, i.e. `trim()` is called on the `String` returned by `get(i)` (which could be `null`).

Comment: You can check that empty string should not be added to arraylist. so check s is not empty before adding to email list here. emails.add(s);

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(filepath);
            ArrayList<String> emails =new ArrayList<>();
              String s;

             while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
                 if(!s.trim().isEmpty()) {
                     emails.add(s);
                 }
              }
                   in.close();

          
          InternetAddress[] addresses = new InternetAddress[emails.size()];
             for (int i =0;i < emails.size();i++) {
             try {
                 addresses[i] = new InternetAddress(emails.get(i)); // line cause the problem
     
        // addresses[i] = new InternetAddress(props.getProperty(emails.get(i).trim()));
                        } catch (AddressException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                   }

                   message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addresses);

               } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
```

This is code improvement.

Comment: Please explain why/how this code solves OP issue ;)

Comment: Per my understanding we are adding trimmed string which have length greater than zero else not. Which means it will always have a value. So as he is checking after extracting from list that is not required because string already trimmed in list. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I meant edit your answer so that it doesn't contains only some code without explanation ;) In order for OP and others to understand where is the issue and how this code solves it.